# there was an error 3134: syntax error in insert into

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert data from two different tables to one table, but the data is not getting imported. I am getting subject error.

```
sql = " INSERT INTO TblUserApps ( TblUserDatabase_[ID], [EmployeeName], [EmpCode], [PFNo], [Department_ID], " _
       & " [AICCallAutomation(CAA)], [AICChat], [AICEmail], [AICMailview], [AICVoice], [BulkSMS], [ComplaintHandlingSystem-GQ&DQ], " _
       & " [CSRScript], [ComplaintManagementSystem-C&WS], [DWS], [E4ME], [EMCais], [ESMA], [MessageBoard], [OnlineTest], [OPMIS], " _
       & " [PMS-PortManagementSystem], [SoftexAccess], [StaffDB], [WFMRTA-CC], [ACDAccess], [ComplaintManagementSystem-ES], " _
       & " [HarmonyPMSRecording], [SMSIntranetApplication], [DQVaretisAgent], [InformationService], [WFMRTA-DQ], [UCIAgent], " _
       & " [CBCMInitialPrestige], [KB], [InternetBrowsing], [CIM], [eBill], [NBA], [CBCMInitialALL], [KBIS], " _
       & " [CBCMInitialSales], [KBHS&MS], [KBECS], [Weyak], [Greetune], [EMS], [Motive], [LoyaltyAccess], [NBAAccessEnabling], [ECCF], " _
       & " [ACS], [700#], [SAR], [CBCM], [SharedDrive], [SharePointKB], [ECCFAdmin], [DOP], [SOH], [BBPartner], [EMSSMS], [EMSTicketing], [UserName] ) " _
       & " SELECT TblUserDatabase.[ID], TblUserDatabase.[EmployeeName], TblUserDatabase.[EmpCode], TblUserDatabase.[PFNo], " _
       & " TblUserDatabase.[Department_ID], TblAppsSecs.[AICCallAutomation(CAA)], TblAppsSecs.[AICChat], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[AICEmail], TblAppsSecs.[AICMailview], TblAppsSecs.[AICVoice], TblAppsSecs.[BulkSMS], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[ComplaintHandlingSystem-GQ&DQ], TblAppsSecs.[CSRScript], TblAppsSecs.[ComplaintManagementSystem-C&WS], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[DWS], TblAppsSecs.[E4ME], TblAppsSecs.[EMCais], TblAppsSecs.[ESMA], TblAppsSecs.[MessageBoard], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[OnlineTest], TblAppsSecs.[OPMIS], TblAppsSecs.[PMS-PortManagementSystem], TblAppsSecs.[SoftexAccess], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[StaffDB], TblAppsSecs.[WFMRTA-CC], TblAppsSecs.[ACDAccess], TblAppsSecs.[ComplaintManagementSystem-ES], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[HarmonyPMSRecording], TblAppsSecs.[SMSIntranetApplication], TblAppsSecs.[DQVaretisAgent], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[InformationService], TblAppsSecs.[WFMRTA-DQ], TblAppsSecs.[UCIAgent], TblAppsSecs.[CBCMInitialPrestige], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[KB], TblAppsSecs.[InternetBrowsing], TblAppsSecs[CIM], TblAppsSecs.[eBill], TblAppsSecs.[NBA], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[CBCMInitialALL], TblAppsSecs.[KBIS], TblAppsSecs[CBCMInitialSales], TblAppsSecs.[KBHS&MS], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[KBECS], TblAppsSecs.[Weyak], TblAppsSecs.[Greetune], TblAppsSecs.[EMS], TblAppsSecs.[Motive], " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[LoyaltyAccess], TblAppsSecs.[NBAAccessEnabling], TblAppsSecs.[ECCF], TblAppsSecs.[ACS], TblAppsSecs.[700#], TblAppsSecs.SAR, TblAppsSecs.CBCM, " _
       & " TblAppsSecs.[SharedDrive], TblAppsSecs.[SharePointKB], TblAppsSecs.[ECCFAdmin], TblAppsSecs.[DOP], TblAppsSecs.[SOH], TblAppsSecs.[BBPartner], TblAppsSecs.[EMSSMS], TblAppsSecs.[EMSTicketing], TblAppsSecs.[Username] " _
       & " FROM TblUserDatabase, TblAppsSecs " _
       & " WHERE TblUserDatabase.[Department_ID] = TblUserApps.[Department_ID] " _
       & " AND TblUserDatabase.Batchnumber = '" & BatchNumber & "' "

DoCmd.RunSQL sql
```

Struggling to solve this. Please support.

Comment: Print out the value of the string, sql and review it.

Comment: No aliases for large tables in a implicit join using a dynamic query and a probalby implict cast in BatchNumber (inserting redundant data?) despistes this ulgy thing makes my eyes bleed please use the profiler tool to check what actually hits the DBMS engine, also can be more easy to find the error (a misplaced quote for example)

Answer (score 1):

You have written:

```
& " FROM TblUserDatabase, TblAppsSecs " _
& " WHERE TblUserDatabase.[Department_ID] = TblUserApps.[Department_ID] " _
```

In FROM use tables: `TblUserDatabase`, `TblAppsSecs`

In WHERE use tables: `TblUserDatabase` and `TblUserApps`

Where do you have defined `TblUserApps`?

Comment: It was a mistake while troubleshooting.

Comment: I even tried " WHERE TblUserDatabase.[Department_ID] = TblAppsSecs.[ID]  ".